# Angular: avoid calling observable nested inside another observable

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx

I have the following code that makes some API calls when a cart is found using the zip operator when the component loads.

```
  ngOnInit() {
    const deliveryModes$ = this.checkoutService.getDeliveryModes();
    const deliveryCountries$ = this.checkoutService.getDeliveryCountries();
    const paymentMode$ = this.checkoutService.getPaymentModeList();

    this.store.select('cart').subscribe((cart: Cart) => {
      if (cart) {
        if (cart.entries.length > 0) {
          this.cart = cart;
          Observable.zip(deliveryModes$, deliveryCountries$, paymentMode$)
            .subscribe(serviceList => {
              this.deliveryModes = serviceList[0];
              this.deliveryCountries = serviceList[1];
              this.paymentModes = serviceList[2];
              this.paymentMethod = this.paymentModes[0].code;
              if (this.paymentMethod === 'paymetric') {
                this.getPaymetricIframe();
              }
              this.initCheckoutForm();
            });
        } else {
          this.router.navigate(['/']);
        }
      } else {
        this.router.navigate(['/']);
      }
    });
  }
```

The problem I am facing is that I have some code somewhere else that updates the cart, and therefore this code will be called again (since it is subscribing to cart) which means that the three calls will be made again, and I dont want that. Those three services should be called only once when the component initializes.

I could add something like to avoid calling the Observable.zip and it works

```
if(this.cartInitialized) { 
   return 
}
```

but I was wondering if there is a better design for this block of code.

Comment: why not unsubscribe from the cart's subscription after the first execution ?

Comment: @ThirueswaranRajagopalan  Because I want to still update the cart in this component when the cart changes.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, does it though? From what I understand `ngOnInit` is only called once, and the calls to `checkoutService` are outside of the `subscribe` block of the `ngrx/store select` method; thus, api calls to your backend service will be performed once on component load irrespective of how many updates are made to `cart`.

Comment: @jrhee17 yes, I had initially those calls inside the store subscription, so I took them out, and I still had the issue.

Comment: interesting. What is `typeof deliveryModes$` though? They should also be `Observable` right? I do know that `Observable.zip` in itself doesn't actually perform requests, so doesn't really make sense that they would still perform api calls. Are you certain `checkoutService` isn't called anywhere else?

Comment: do you also need to navigate to root if the cart is empty ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below in an imitaion of the working sample @ https://jsfiddle.net/a8yc1ngn/4/

```
ngOnInit() {
    const deliveryModes$ = this.checkoutService.getDeliveryModes();
    const deliveryCountries$ = this.checkoutService.getDeliveryCountries();
    const paymentMode$ = this.checkoutService.getPaymentModeList();

    /*  subscribe while cart is valid ...
        NOTE: replace takeWhile with filter, if navigation to root is not necessary ..*/
    const cartChange$ = this.store.select('cart').takeWhile((cart :Cart) => cart && cart.entries.length);
    /*  keep updating local cart with changes....
        navigate to root is cart is invalid, means subcription is completed ...*/
    cartChange$.subscribe((cart :Cart) => this.cart = cart,
        () => console.log('errr ..')  , 
        () => this.router.navigate(['/']));
    /*  first time a cart update comes, fetch serviceList(s) ... */
    cartChange$.take(1)
        .mergeMap(() => Observable.zip(deliveryModes$, deliveryCountries$, paymentMode$))
        .subscribe(serviceList => {
            /* things to do .... */
        });
}
```

Comment: Just a quick question, from what I know mergeMap will merge the source with the inner subscription (the zipped services).. but how come then the serviceList variable doesnt have the cart in the output as well?

Comment: My pleasure. Since we are not specifying the result selector/transfor it emits the inner's. Check on http://rxmarbles.com/#mergeMap and http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-mergeMap

Comment: Gotcha! Thanks again! : )